# Does is_page() work in WP plugins php file?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is `is_page()` supposed to work from a plugin's php file? Specifically, I'm using the NextGen gallery to control an enqueue of scripts and styles. I've tested it and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: "I've tested and it seems it doesn't." ok, then there is your answer

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your plugin is doing and when this specific code is being ran, it may be getting executed while inside of The Loop. If this is the case, then `is_page()` won't work. From the docs:

> Due to certain global variables being overwritten during The Loop is_page() will not work. In order to use it after The Loop you must call wp_reset_query() after The Loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think as long as you insert:

```
global $wpdb;
```

Into your plugin/function, you should be able to use `is_page()`, as long as it's not hooked inside the loop.